# Simple creation of folder under SDCARD in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've used the code to create a folder under SD card. But the folder never creates.I've added uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  to manifest.

```
 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Images");
       folder.mkdirs();


       if(folder.exists()){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }else{

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," not exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

Comment: I've just started learning Android development...It would be great if anybody could help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code to debug whether you can actually write on the external storage or not:

```
Log.d("MyActivity", "Can write: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite());
```

and verify the result of mkdirs too:

```
boolean result = folder.mkdirs();
Log.d("MyActivity", "mkdirs: " + result);
```

Comment: The Log.d("MyActivity", "Can write: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()); statement displays Can Write:false.But Ive added  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" to my manifest.Any other factors ?

Comment: if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard mounted and writable");
} shows sdcard mounted and writable

Answer (score 0):

You should also add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding...But it does'nt work ! The if condition in the code shows "not exists".Any other factors ?

Comment: You can create a File this way : `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Images");` And if you need to create only one dir, use: `directory.mkdir()`. Did you check : `folder.getPath()` ? Does it look like what it should be to you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
File directory = new File(pathname);
                if (directory != null && !directory.exists()
                        && !directory.mkdirs()) {
                    try {
                        throw new IOException("Cannot create dir "
                                + directory.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check the flow of Log-->

```
      //First check if the sd card is mounted or not      
         if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))

                {
                   // sd card mounted
                   Log.d("SDCard", "SDcard is present");
                }  

                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +"Images/");
             if(!folder.exists())

              {
                folder.mkdirs();
                Log.d("SDcard", "Folder created");
              }   
            else
         {
                Log.d("SDCard", "Folder already exists");
         }       
     }
```

Comment: if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) shows sd card is mounted. But Log.d("MyActivity", "Can write: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()); displays Can Write:false.

Comment: if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    Log.d("Test", "sdcard mounted and writable");
} shows sdcard mounted and writable

Comment: any number of times I initiate the folder creation (!folder.exists()) is true...the folder is never created

Comment: Seems like a problem of permission.. Remove permission from manifest and re-add 'em.

Comment: yes right ! I added the permission before the application block and it works fine now..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! I have added the  block in the wrong section of the manifest. It should precede or follow the  section.